# Joomla 3.4.3 mail function

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, emails

I built a custom component using the `$mail = JFactory::getMailer();` as shown on this page: https://docs.joomla.org/Sending_email_from_extensions.

I'm using `mailtrap.io` to catch the sent mail for testing.

It worked fine for all the Joomla 3.4 releases until 3.4.3, at which point it no longer works. The mail still gets sent, but unless I set the `$mail->isHTML(true);` flag, there's no body content in the message (subject, reply to, etc. still gets through fine).

If I `var_dump` the `$mail` variable, the `$body` content appears correct-- it's not that the variable isn't being set. It seems like it's just not making it out the door.

Has anyone run into this?

Comment: I was reading through the Joomla commits recently and if I remember correctly, PHPMailer was updated. Perhaps this update is the cause. I might run a test today

Comment: Use a diff to check changes in Mailer classes. It is possible it is framework related.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the case on sendgrid. It works OK with text or html mails.

```
    $mailer = JFactory::getMailer();
    $config = JFactory::getConfig();
    $sender = array(
            $config->get($this->get('mail_sender_email')),
            $config->get($this->get('mail_sender_name'))
    );
    $mailer->setSender($sender);        
    $mailer->isHtml(false); // Or, true
    $mailer->SetFrom($sender_mail, $sender_name);
    $mailer->AddAddress($recipient_mail);
    $mailer->Subject = 'A Subject';
    $mailer->Body = '<p>Body</p>';
    $mailer->Send();
```

I guess you should have some incompatibility with mailtrap.